# Kibana - Calculating duration between events

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am pushing events directly into the elastic search rest API, in the following format:

- Timestamp
- RequestId
- EventName

I would like to bucket by RequestId and then subtract the max and min Timestamps to calculate duration between events in Kibana.

**I can quite easily bucket them in Kibana, although its not intuitive to know how to calculate the duration.  I have been changing the JSON input to try and get it to render something sensible without luck.**

I have managed to achieve what I want using the elastic search API directly:

```js
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { },
  "aggs": {
    "requests_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "requestId",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_date": {
          "min": {
            "field": "timeStamp"
          }
        },
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timeStamp"
          }
        },
        "duration" : {
         "bucket_script" : {
          "buckets_path" : {
       "minDate" : "min_date",
       "maxDate" : "max_date"
      },
    "script" : "maxDate-minDate"
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I "visualise" this in Kibana as a simple line graph?